# newsletter in c#

Tags: c#, html

i am using c# to send mail. in my mail i used three images one for background, one for headerimage and last for footer image..
but the problem is i am not getting the background image when i recieve the mail..
my code for the image is:

```
  imgAtt.ContentId = "Winter.jpg";
ingatt1.ContentId = "images5.jpg";

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(to);
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
                    mail.Subject = "In line image test";
                    mail.Body = "<html><body>" +
                    "<div style=\"width:300px; height:300px;border:4px solid; background-image:'cid:"+ingatt.ContentId+"\"> " +                 
                    "<center>" +
                    "<img style=\"width:100px; height:100px;\" src=\'cid:" + imgAtt.ContentId + "' /> " +
                    "</center>" +
                    "</div> " +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>";
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

please someone help me..

Comment: Need more information. (1) Does your e-mail client support background images? (2) Is the src URL correct? It looks like the image URL is local to your application. (3) What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: i am getting the image of src but i am not geeting image of div..there seems some mistake in div tag which i am not getting..

Comment: @cs: is gmail support background image..

Comment: i think you would be more likely to get two images if you used two different urls instead of using the same one twice.

Comment: @yaur: i am using two different image url's..

Answer (score 2):

with this

```
ingatt1.ContentId = "images5.jpg
```

this

```
"<div style=\"width:300px; height:300px;border:4px solid; background-image:'cid:"+ingAtt.ContentId+"\"> " +
```

should be this

```
"<div style=\"width:300px; height:300px;border:4px solid; background-image:'cid:"+ingatt1.ContentId+"\"> " +
```

Comment: no its not working....using this the div image goes to attachments..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"<div style=\"width:300px; height:300px;border:4px solid; background-image: url('cid:"+ingatt.ContentId+"')\"> " +
```

That should result in the correct format of the `background-image` css rule ( http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp )

Comment: Peter vos: no it's not working. using this he div image goes to the attachements..